# How do I separate joined meshes for texturing

Tags: texturing, vertex-groups, .fbx

I'm going to try to describe my problem, but I may have some of the terminology wrong.  I have a figure in FBX format that is made up of four separate meshes joined together to create a combined figure.  Parts A, B, C, and D should have texture sets A, B, C, and D, respectively, but when I load the FBX in Blender, texture set D is applied to all parts.

In object mode, the figure is animated, and all four parts are separated, which makes it easy to figure out which vertex groups belong to each mesh.  The problem is that when I go into Edit mode, all four parts are joined together, which makes it difficult to separate them so I can apply the correct textures.  What is an efficient way to deal with this, so I'm not selecting individual faces one by one?

Comment: I don't think they should be together in edit mode if they're separate in Object mode. Are you sure you don't have them all selected before going into edit mode?

Comment: As Agnivesh says, use L to select each separate mesh, and assign a different material to each mesh so that you'll be able to give them a different texture

Answer (score 1):

Hover your mouse over a single mesh part and <kbd>L</kbd> that should select a loose/detached mesh.

Comment: That works if you know which body parts belong to which mesh.  In Object mode, the various meshes come together to form one figure or separate, depending on where they are in the animation.  It's easy to see which vertex groups belong to which of the four meshes when they're separated like that, but you can't select their vertices when they're in Object mode, or so it seems.  When I switch to Edit mode, the skeleton reverts to Rest Position, and all four parts are intertwined with each other.